# Unrecognised XML Characters when parsing in Classic ASP

Tags: xml, parsing, asp-classic

Hey I am having issues parsing XML file,

Theres seems an unrecognised symbol after each new line. When im parsing this is Classic ASP and print out to screen it is appearing as "?" but when i do I.e replace(text,"?","LOL") its not replacing so its not a normal "?" I think.

How can I capture and filter out this symbol ?

Note this is done in classic ASP

Comment: Can you post your xml file and the code you use to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like the document encoding isn't perhaps what you expect it to be. Does the XML file have an encoding defined?

Check out this for more info on encoding:
[Internationalization and Classic ASP](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is some of the code

Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

```
    If (fs.FileExists(path))Then
        issueId = id
        set objDom = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
        objDom.async="false"
        objDom.load(path)
        Set root = objDom.DocumentElement
        '\Get the <Content> element
        set contentElement = root.selectSingleNode("content")
        'Response.Write("gets here")
        loadDom = true
    else
        loadDom = false
    end if
```

Then I just loop through each node
for each node in contentElement.childNodes..